# how Alert coming when button is disabled jquery?

Tags: jquery

> i have made this function which should alert when click but it's also
>   firing when the button is Disabled

```
checker = $("#CP_Main_btnCancelItem").button().click(function () {
              var checkedCount = $('#CP_Main_gvPOItems input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
              if (checkedCount == 0) {
                  alert('No check-box is selected');
              }
          });
```

**.ASPX**

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnCancelItem" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"OnClientClick="return Confirmationbox();">&nbsp;Cancel Item</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnval" value=0 runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide us your HTML code?

Comment: Are you adding any css class to the button to disable?

Comment: Where is this element `CP_Main_btnCancelItem` in your code ?

Comment: if you use `length` to find it's existence then use `visible` to check it's visible or not. like `var checkedCount = $('#CP_Main_gvPOItems input[type=checkbox]:checked:visible').length;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the the element `disable` property you need to use `:disabled`.

```
    checker = $("#CP_Main_btnCancelItem").button().click(function () {
                var checkedCount = $('#CP_Main_gvPOItems input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;

    var isDisabled  = $(checkedCount).is(':disabled');

                  if (isDisabled) {
                      alert('No check-box is selected');
                  }
              });
```

Markup

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnCancelItem" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"OnClientClick="return Confirmationbox();">&nbsp;Cancel Item</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnval" value=0 runat="server"/>
```

Comment: but i think visible is not the issue Disable and enable are